# Fill Excel VBA Forms and submit using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

My excel file has a VBA macro button. Upon clicking the button, it invokes a function named `MyMacro`. The process in turn returns a form named `SampleForm` (like below) where the end user has to enter the **Name** and then click on **OK** to complete the operation.

[image: SampleForm]

**Name** would be always same for a given user. Let us assume the value of the Name input is always **John**.

My goal is to automate this whole operation using Powershell. I am calling the concerned macro via `Run("MyMacro")`. Powershell successfully invokes the macro function, shows the form and then waits for input to proceed further. At this stage, I am clueless on how to access `SampleForm` from Powershell, fill it and then submit.

```
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$FilePath = 'MyFile.xls'
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$App = $excel.Application
$App.Run("MyMacro")
```

Comment: Can you simulate the click of the "Tab" button through PowerShell?

Comment: if you look at this blog post it might get you started in the right direction: http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powershell/powershell-poshgui-convert-user-to-sid-and-vice-versa-using

Comment: Sapien.com has PowerShell Studio that you can get a 30 day trial of that will also help get you started. this site will also help http://www.poshgui.com

Comment: I would probably just rewrite the VBA entirely in Powershell if this were my issue to solve. If that is not an option then you can load the worksheet and access the OLE objects on it. I don't have the time to write a proper answer but this link shows doing it with a checkbox. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09e31365-2997-48ff-9e98-b01468ed805c/powershell-and-excels-form-controls?forum=exceldev